# RadPanel does not appear when click on RadTab , Telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

There is already half developed Web page. In which there are 4 RadTabs. On particular tab click, related Panel will open below.
Now, I have to add one more Tab named as "Invoice" and have to open a panel on tab click.
When I try to add new Tab and then click on Tab, it does not open any panel below.

Below is the demo code I tried but no luck.

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server">
    <Windows>
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="rwBilling" Title="ITSSC Billing" runat="server" ReloadOnShow="true" Modal="true"
            ShowContentDuringLoad="false" Animation="Fade" Width="480px" Height="480px"
            EnableEmbeddedSkins="False" Skin="MetroRed" />
    </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>

<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" Transparency="20"
     Width="100%" Height="100%">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle"></asp:Image>
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>

Demo

    <br />
    <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedSkins="False" OnClientTabSelected="OnClientTabSelected"
        Skin="MetroRed" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1" SelectedIndex="0" CssClass="tabStrip"
        Width="100%">
        <Tabs>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="Service Proposals" Selected="True">
            </telerik:RadTab>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="Advance Search">
            </telerik:RadTab>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="Section Revenue Report">
            </telerik:RadTab>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="Generate Invoices">
            </telerik:RadTab>
        </Tabs>
    </telerik:RadTabStrip>


    <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage1" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" Width="100%">

        <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView1" runat="server" Width="100%" BorderStyle="Groove"
            BorderColor="Red" BorderWidth="1px">

            Test

        </telerik:RadPageView>


        <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView2" runat="server" Width="100%" BorderStyle="Groove"
            BorderColor="Red" BorderWidth="1px">

            Test 1

       </telerik:RadPageView>

        <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView3" runat="server" Width="100%" BorderStyle="Groove"
            BorderColor="Red" BorderWidth="1px">

            Test 2

       </telerik:RadPageView>

        <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView4" runat="server" Width="100%" BorderStyle="Groove"
            BorderColor="Red" BorderWidth="1px">

            Test 3

       </telerik:RadPageView>
```

I am very new in Telerik, so please let me know the solution of this. I am not getting how to achieve this. Please reply

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Due to missing "Orientation" Property, it was not working.

```
<telerik:RadTabStrip Orientation="HorizontalTop"
```